# Is there a way to use ReJSON with GEOADD?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I need to store the location of an object and some additional data about that object. If there is a way that I can do something like the following

GEOADD stores long lat {key1: val1, key2: val2, ...}

The intent is to run a single query for proximity and get the related data along with it, rather than running multiple queries to get all the store keys which are in a certain proximity and THEN using those keys to get data for those stores.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ReJSON provides a new data type for Redis (for JSON objects, naturally) whereas Geo Sets' (implemented with Sorted Sets) are Redis Strings. So, the short answer is **no**.

Besides the technical impossibility, you should also think whether you need ReJSON at all - it's main benefit is allowing semi-efficient read/write access to sub-elements, and in your case it looks like you're trying to "get" the entire JSON value.

You **can** do a single query and get the serialized JSON (Redis String) as long as all you "JSON"s are unique. If they are not, make them so (i.e. add some `id` key in them or something). Doing the query will actually return these serialized JSON Strings to your client where you can parse them.